# Cannot install any version of Views

Tags: views, 7

Sorry, I'm very newbie to Drupal. I have my new website with Godaddy, I installed Drupal, , and I'm trying to install "Views", but none of the versions I try to install are working. Through the upload a module link, I put the path to the file, it starts to upload, but sometimes it returns me to the original upload module page, or I get a blank page.
Then, I tried through the URL link, and I get messages like this one:
"
Uncaught exception thrown in session handler.

PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'uid' cannot be null: UPDATE {sessions} SET uid=:db_update_placeholder_0, cache=:db_update_placeholder_1, hostname=:db_update_placeholder_2, session=:db_update_placeholder_3, timestamp=:db_update_placeholder_4 WHERE ( (sid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (ssid = :db_condition_placeholder_1) ); Array ( [:db_update_placeholder_0] => [:db_update_placeholder_1] => 0 [:db_update_placeholder_2] => 186.31.188.159 [:db_update_placeholder_3] => overlay_refresh_parent|b:1; [:db_update_placeholder_4] => 1420733668 [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => vYQ5soHEzo2a4yioZAIpOtgpf0qdJGqEUNOSy7erQ8c [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => ) in _drupal_session_write() (line 209 of G:\PleskVhosts\inversiones360.com\httpdocs\drupal\includes\session.inc).
"

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Marcel

Comment: Have you updated Drupal Core or contrib modules lately? Ran DB updates as well? I would check there first to make sure that there isn't a pending update that needs to be ran. What version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7.34, the diagnostics says it's all modules up to date.

Comment: Actually go to http://example.com/update.php (replace example.com with your domain) to make sure your DB updates have all been ran, after pressing continue you will either see "No pending updates" or the updates that need to be ran.

Comment: It says "All of your projects are up to date."

Comment: That's not the correct message, you actually need to physically go to mysite.com/update.php to see the database updates, that's the project code updates message at /admin/reports/updates/update pls check /update.php this is where database updates are performed.

Comment: OK, thank you. Now it says "No pending updates."

Comment: Was there Database updates? and after these updates did you clear cache and try to install Views again? Does this happen with any other module install?

Comment: No any updates. I cleaned cache. It happened initially with Ctools via upload from my computer, then when I tried via ftp it worked well. Now with Views I get the same error:

Comment: PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column &#039;uid&#039; cannot be null: UPDATE {sessions} SET uid=:db_update_placeholder_0, cache=:db_update_placeholder_1, hostname=:db_update_placeholder_2, session=:db_update_placeholder_3, timestamp=:db_update_placeholder_4 WHERE ( (sid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (ssid = :db_condition_placeholder_1) ); Array ( [:db_update_placeholder_0] =&gt; [:db_update_placeholder_1] =&gt; 0 [:db_update_placeholder_2] =&gt; 186.31.188.159 [:db_update_placeholder_3] =&gt; batches|a:1:{i:4;b:1;}

Comment: in _drupal_session_write() (line 209 of G:\PleskVhosts\inversiones360.com\httpdocs\drupal\includes\session.inc).

Comment: You said this is hosted on godaddy right? Chances are that if the above steps aren't working that you could be using up your memory (or used it up during install and something didn't process right) and you either need to up your plan or try again with a fresh install. The shared hosting piece puts a hamper on what can be done about fixing this but I would try getting the server logs as well if they will let you see them.